# How could I call a file in parent python file with relative path?

Tags: python

Just like this [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4cqV.png) .

When I import the modules in "cudamat.py" or "eignmat.py". I got a **"File Not Found Problem"**. Actually, in these two file, the author handle the **"libeigenmat.so"**  with relative path.

```
with open("libeigenmat.so", 'r') as file:
     file.read()
```

But when I run the "Run_*.py", I am in the subfolder, so the python interpreter cannot find "libeigenmat.so".

So, could you guys help me to figure out this question? How could I call a parent method with the file operation in a relative path? More specifically, How could I change the **eignmat.py** or **cudamat.py** to make these two file available in arbitrary path?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> More specifically, How could I change the eignmat.py or cudamat.py to make these two file available in arbitrary path?

Get the absolute path first then combine it with the file could make your aim.

```
import os

file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)).replace('\\', '/')

with open(os.path.join(file_path, "libeigenmat.so"), 'r') as file:
    a = file.read()
```

Comment: Thanks very much,it is also my intuitive idea. But I am stuck in 'get absolute path', I have no idea about how to get the absolute path of 'libeigenmat.so'  to make it available in any platform. So i guess my question is equal to how to get a file's absolute path in any platform where I only know it exist in my project(Just a relative path).

Comment: the filepath above already a absolute path, and it can work on windows/linux/mac, you can have a try

Comment: Thanks again. The keyword '__file__' really help me figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.` symbol to signify a higher directory in the hierarchy, putting a single `.` at the start of a filepath however refers to "the folder than this file is in" so to get a file from the parent directory, you would use `..`

```
with open("../libeigenmat.so", 'r') as file:
     file.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

`run` commands should really always be called from the root of the project.  Similarly, you should wrap scripts with importable functions into a `package`. There are ways to do it differently, such as using `sys.path.append` or using relative imports but if you are a beginner with how Python deals with imports, these are really two good rules of thumb to follow. Actually even if you are not a beginner this is good practice

Restructure your project as follows:

```
parent\
   run.py
   my_package\
       eigenmat.py
       cudamat.py
       __init__.py
```

The `__init__.py` tells Python to consinder the folder where it lies as the contents of an importable module. Within `run.py`, use the statements `from my_package import eigenmat` or `from my_package import cudamat`. You can use the exact same statements to import between `eigenmat.py` and `cudamat.py` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [os.getcwd()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd) to fetch current working directory and use [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to construct a path to your file so that it would always find correct path to your file as long as you are executing your code from base directory.

```html
import os


with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'libeigenmat.so'), 'r') as file:
     file.read()
```